# JSON parsed in onreadystatechange function behaves weird outside the function. Can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, json

```
const lBtn=document.querySelector("#lArrow");
const rBtn=document.querySelector("#rArrow");
const rstBtn=document.querySelector("#btn");
const imgSlot=document.querySelector("figure");

const testP=document.querySelector("#test");

var items;

var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET","dataimage.json",true);
req.onreadystatechange=()=>{
    if((req.readyState==4) && (req.status>=200 && req.status<400)){
        items=JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        
        var item;var output;
        output="<ol>";
        for (item in items){
            output+="<li>"+items[item].Name+": "+items[item].Image+"</li>";
        }
        output+="</ol>";
        testP.innerHTML=output;

    }
    
}
req.send();

console.log(items);
```

inside the function, the JSON file was parsed correctly and can be populated into a <p> element;

outside, `console.log(items)` returned `undefined`

However in the console, when typing `items' manually and specifying any index number, correct values are displayed.

How can I possibly get the parsed JSON object outside? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of
[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is limited.  Just a guess, but you could try passing in "items" as an argument, e.g.

```
...
req.onreadystatechange=(items)=>{
...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

- it's give you undefined because the values isn't assigned yet - you tested this variable before sending the request so you should to test him after getting the data
- if you wants to work with data out of the onreadystatechange or onloadend events can try Promise

```
const lBtn=document.querySelector("#lArrow");
const rBtn=document.querySelector("#rArrow");
const rstBtn=document.querySelector("#btn");
const imgSlot=document.querySelector("figure");
const testP=document.querySelector("#test");
var items;
var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET","dataimage.json",true);
var _promise = function () { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        req.onloadend = (data) => {
            if((data.currentTarget.readyState==4) && (data.currentTarget.status>=200 && data.currentTarget.status<400)){
              var obj =JSON.parse(data.currentTarget.responseText);
              resolve(obj)
            }
        }
    })
}
_promise().then(res => { 
   items = res;
    console.log(items);
   var item;var output;
        output="<ol>";
        for (item in items){
            output+="<li>"+items[item].Name+": "+items[item].Image+"</li>";
        }
        output+="</ol>";
         testP.innerHTML=output;
       
})
req.send();
```